# Retry Failed HTTP Request with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

While processing my data, I need to call an endpoint. I'm wondering how to implement a retryable mechanism in Spark. After X retries, how can I aggregate failed requests?

Comment: I found this resource for aggregating failed requests - https://anish749.github.io/spark/exception-handling-spark-data-frames/

Answer (score 0):

Spark is not meant to be used for HTTP requests.

You can use retry from Akka: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/futures.html#retry

Also other Java libraries for HTTP client, like Apache HTTPClient have the retry feature.

Comment: @Sahil you can use the usual `SparkSession.parallelize()` as described here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections

Comment: are you saying to use `SparkSession.parallelize()` to aggregate failed HTTP rows in a separate dataframe? I need to aggregate in the catch clause on a per row basis in my map function